# HTML position = center-10px

Tags: html, css, center

I am making an HTML website. I have an map as an background picture and I need a button to be on the map. Like this: 
[image: This is how it should look like]

But when I start scaling my site, this happens:[image]
I know what is the problem: the position of the pictures is `center-X px` and `center-Y px`, not `margin: 40% 0px 0px 20%`. But how to do that? `position: absolute; left: 50%-30px; top: 50%-83px` doesn´t work.

Comment: I think you should keep images fixed in those divs

Comment: You can use calc() . : `left: calc(50% - 30px);` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Post a [mcve] please so that we can see the exact problem

Comment: @G-Cyr No, that does´t work. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/p8P3s)

Comment: Screenshots are useless, it doesn't show your HTML structure , code nor CSS. There is no way for any of us to reproduce your issue. It can be anything, starting from a single typo in your code .calc() works, it is what you try to do that does not. wrong understanding of the rule, wrong method, a typo somewhere, wrong selector, ...  share enough of your code that DO show your issue. From there, you will have a chance to get efficient help and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative margins which has better support than [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -83px;
margin-left: -30px;
```

If you already have margins, you can just minus them from there. However, if they are defined as percentages or `em`'s, then you're going to have to convert them accordingly.

Comment: i think he already have margin defined, so better use calc as said in comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of people have mentioned using absolute margins (which would work), however there is another approach with the implementation of `transform: translate`.

In the example below, the inner `img` is always centered in its containing div which I believe would also meet your needs. I also added some random animation to the box so that you can see how effectively this positions itself.

```js
setInterval(randomAnimation, 500);

function randomAnimation() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 0));
  if (random == 0)
    $(".box").animate({
      top: "+=50"
    });
  else if (random == 1)
    $(".box").animate({
      left: "+=50"
    });
  else if (random == 2)
    $(".box").animate({
      top: "-=50"
    });
  else
  $(".box").animate({
      height: "+=50"
    });
}
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/150x100/ff0000/ffffff)
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You will want the image to be relative to the background image (div container with the map as background image):

```
position: relative; left: 30px; top: 83px
```

Comment: what have you done, can you explain ? and you are using invalid CSS

Comment: I'm just giving an example. You will want the background image literally the background image of a 'container' div. Then you can position the caption images 'relative' to the background image by using left and top.